# How to increase the font size of the legend in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, seaborn

I have the following codes to create a Seaborn strip plot. I am having a hard time figuring out how to increase the font size of the legend appearing in the plot.

```py
g=sns.stripplot(x="Market", y="Rate", hue="Group",data=myBenchmarkData, jitter=True, size=12, alpha=0.5)
g.axes.set_title("4* Rate Market and by Hotel Groups for Year 2016",fontsize=25)
g.set_xlabel("Market",fontsize=20)
g.set_ylabel("Rate (in EUR)",fontsize=20)
g.tick_params(labelsize=15)
plt.savefig ('benchmark1.png')
```

I am OK with my x-axis and y-axis labels font size but the font size of the legend in my plot is small. How to change it?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Use matplotlib function `setp` according to this example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

ax = sns.stripplot(x="sex", y="total_bill", hue="day", data=tips, jitter=True)
plt.setp(ax.get_legend().get_texts(), fontsize='22') # for legend text
plt.setp(ax.get_legend().get_title(), fontsize='32') # for legend title

plt.show()
```

[image]

Another way is to change `font_scale` of all graph with `plotting_context`:
http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.plotting_context.html

Comment: How to do this using a factorplot? I get the error: `AttributeError: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'get_legend'`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50201227/how-to-increase-the-font-size-of-the-legend-in-my-seaborn-facetplot/

Comment: But what can be done to make the marker sizes in the legend match the marker sizes in the plot?

Comment: @Archie The FacetGrid object has a legend in its `_legend` attribute. So you would change it using `setp(g._legend.get_title(), fontsize=32)`.

Comment: For me using a catplot (FaceGrid) this worked in the end `sns.move_legend(g.ax, "upper right", fontsize=15)`

Answer (score 28):

There is a much easier way to do this today, simply set up your figure and then call

```
plt.legend(fontsize='x-large', title_fontsize='40')
```

https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html

Might depend on the version of matplotlib you're using. I'm using 2.2.3 and it has the `fontsize` parameter but not the `title_fontsize`.