# How to increase the font size of the FactorPlot/FacetGrid legend

Tags: python, seaborn, facet-grid

The instructions from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44880444/how-to-increase-the-font-size-of-the-legend-in-my-seaborn-plot) don't work for Seaborn FacetPlots. Would it be possible to get the method to do the same?

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328003/how-can-i-change-the-font-size-using-seaborn-facetgrid)

Comment: I only want to modify the legend font size(title/text separately) - just like in the question linked above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the linked answer you may use `setp` to set the properties (in this case the fontsize of the legend).

The only difference to the linked question is that you need to do that for each axes of the FacetGrid

```
g = FacetGrid( ... )

for ax in g.axes.flat:
    plt.setp(ax.get_legend().get_texts(), fontsize=22)  # for legend text
    plt.setp(ax.get_legend().get_title(), fontsize=32)  # for legend title
```

Comment: This gives the following error: `AttributeError: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'get_legend'`. Its also mentioned in the comment on that linked answer.

Comment: You cannot get this error from the code I propose here.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry didn't notice the change.

Comment: Also to add to this answer, if using a `sns.factorplot`, you need to do `ax[0].get_legend()....`

Comment: This may be deprecated, no longer works. The solution from @Hielke Walinga is currently accurate.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_texts'
`

Answer (score 12):

A facetgrid legend is not part of the axes, but part of the facetgrid object. The legend is still a standard matplotlib legend and can be manipulated as such.

```
plt.setp(g._legend.get_title(), fontsize=20)
```

Where g is your facetgrid object returned after you call the function making it.

Comment: `plt.setp(e._legend.get_texts(), fontsize=40)` work for increase legend text

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a newer version of matplotlib there's an easier way to change legend font sizes -

```
plt.legend(fontsize='x-large', title_fontsize='40')
```

https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html

Might depend on the version of matplotlib you're using. I'm using 2.2.3 and it has the `fontsize` parameter but not the `title_fontsize`.