# Seaborn scatterplot matirix, chage leged, labels and pointsie

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am tyring to use seaborn for a pairplot, i want to:

- Change x,y label size
- Change legennd size
- Change size of points

```py
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_theme(style="ticks")

df = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
sns.pairplot(df, hue="species")
```

when using matplotlib you can do it with:

```py
plt.legend(fontsize=20)
```

however it is creating a second legend for some reason:
[image: second legend from plt.legend]

**EDIT**

Using

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
sns.set_theme(style="ticks")

df = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
ax=sns.pairplot(df, hue="species")

plt.setp(ax.get_legend().get_texts(), fontsize='22') # for legend text
plt.setp(ax.get_legend().get_title(), fontsize='32') # for legend title

plt.show()
```

Does not work:

Out:

```py
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-6ed6c69c9141> in <module>()
      6 ax=sns.pairplot(df, hue="species")
      7 
----> 8 plt.setp(ax.get_legend().get_texts(), fontsize='22') # for legend text
      9 plt.setp(ax.get_legend().get_title(), fontsize='32') # for legend title
     10 

AttributeError: 'PairGrid' object has no attribute 'get_legend'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44880444/how-to-increase-the-font-size-of-the-legend-in-my-seaborn-plot#comment101763170_44882373

Comment: @BigBen, just tried, it still creates a second legend

Comment: ah? ok i must have misread the question

Comment: The linked comment does *not* use `plt.legend`.

Comment: @BigBen, my bad i had scrolled to the second answer. I have updated my question, it still wont work wiht the pairplot though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second attempt is closer. As mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44880444/how-to-increase-the-font-size-of-the-legend-in-my-seaborn-plot#comment101763170_44882373), something like the following:

```
df = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
g = sns.pairplot(df, hue="species")

plt.setp(g._legend.get_title(), fontsize=20)
plt.setp(g._legend.get_texts(), fontsize=20)
```

Comment: Ok, great it works, and can this format be used for the axis labels? 
i am guesing it is something like: plt.setp(g.axis.get_texts(), fontsize=20)

Comment: Perhaps [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36573789/python-seaborn-facetgrid-change-xlabels).

Comment: Ok great, i guess im going to use something other than seaborn as the code becomes complicated if i have to select each label individually.

Comment: @David8 - [another option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31864770/change-font-size-of-facet-titles-using-seaborn-facetgrid-heatmap) and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27714134/9245853)... Not a seaborn expert by any means myself, so learning as I go. Ignore my previous comment.